# Different reference stacks return equals true

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

```
 towers=new ArrayList<>();
 towers.add(new Stack<Integer>());
 towers.add(new Stack<Integer>());
 towers.add(new Stack<Integer>());
```

Why would this return true?

```
  towers.get(1).equals(towers.get(2))
```

Did they somehow implement equals for stacks to check elements instead of the default behaviour which is reference

Answer (score 3):

Because of the `equals` contract for stacks.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html

Follow that to:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

To wit:

> Returns true if and only if the specified Object is also a List, both Lists have the same size, and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two Lists are equal. (Two elements e1 and e2 are equal if `(e1==null ? e2==null : e1.equals(e2))`.)
>
> In other words, two Lists are defined to be equal if they contain the same elements in the same order.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought as well.

Comment: @NathanDrake You don't have to just think it, you can look it up!